# Сокращение времени выполнения запроса

Tags: mysql, база-данных, производительность, highload, innodb

Как составить наиболее производительный запрос к БД (MySQL, InnoDB) в следующей ситуации. Имеется таблица USER_POSTS, где хранятся данные о постах пользователей. В таблице порядка 20 млн. записей о постах пользователей, размер 20Gb, у каждого пользователя в среднем 3000 постов (данные собираются из других социальных сетей). Требуется выводить по 20 записей на страницу, отбираемых по OWNER_ID (владелец профиля) и сортируемых по CREATED (дате создания). По OWNER_ID и CREATED выставлены индексы.

Наиболее простое решение в моем случае будет следующим:

```
SELECT post_id, owner_id, content_text, location_name, provider_id, provider_source_id, provider_source_id_full, provider_source_domain, provider_source_link, provider_source_name, provider_source_photo, provider_post_link, attachment_0_photo, created FROM user_posts WHERE owner_id='30' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Проблема в том, что **до попадания этого запроса в кэш MySQL**, время его выполнения для меня неприемлемо. Пробовал такой вариант:

```
SELECT b.post_id, b.owner_id, b.content_text, b.location_name, b.provider_id, b.provider_source_id, b.provider_source_id_full, b.provider_source_domain, b.provider_source_link, b.provider_source_name, b.provider_source_photo, b.provider_post_link, b.attachment_0_photo, b.created FROM (SELECT post_id FROM user_posts WHERE owner_id='30' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 20) a, user_posts b WHERE b.post_id=a.post_id;
```

Выдает более производительный результат, но все равно достаточно медленно. Как я понял, узким местом является сортировка по полю CREATED. Без нее запрос идет в 5-7 раз быстрее, но ее нельзя убрать. Посты по индексу POST_ID идут не в хронологическом порядке.

Как можно составить более быстрый запрос на основе этих исходных данных? Что еще можно сделать для более производительного выполнения запросов такого типа?

Comment: Используйте индексацию, по полям запроса (where)

Comment: да, уже использую отдельные индексы по OWNER_ID и CREATED, но этого недостаточно для хорошей производительности

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov Отдельные индексы вам ничем помочь не могут. запрос на одну таблицу одновременно может использовать только один индекс. Поэтому сделайте составной индекс (owner_id, created)

Comment: @Mike Да, тоже склоняюсь к этому решению. Еще вопрос, если к составному индексу добавить дополнительное условие (Например, поле FLAG_HIDDEN, которое фильтрует скрытые пользователем посты. 99,9% постов имеют 0, оставшиеся 0,1% - 1), то это сильно повляет на скорость индекса?

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov Вряд ли. зато если оно будет в индексе перед датой, а вы в каком нибудь запросе захотите получить данные без условия по этому полю, очень вероятно что оптимизатор не будет использовать индекс для сортировки

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov И я на знаю как mysql относится к тому, что в индексе дата будет по возрастанию а в запросе по убыванию. И если у него возможность добавить колонку в индекс так же по убыванию. Но если умеет - я бы включил ее в индекс в соответствии с сортировкой, на всякий случай

Comment: @Mike Попробовал, ситуация следующая. Время запроса отчасти сократилось. При дальнейшем росте размера таблицы скорость вывода сообщений находится на стабильном уровне, но хочется ее еще повысить. Как понимаю, все упирается в обратную сортировку по дате, если ее убрать, то скорость возрастает в разы. Чем больше отобранный массив для сортировки, тем больше и время вывода (если у пользователя всего 1000 сообщений, то они обрабатываются в 2 раза быстрее, чем 3000).

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov Это при индексе create index index_x on table_y (owner_id, created desc) ? Т.е. вы его сделали по убыванию ? И что дает explain для этого запроса. Я у себя сейчас попробовал просто планы посмотреть на похожей таблице. в общем, если пытаться сортировать не по полю в индексе то в последней колонке появляется `using filesort`, вот если у вас этот `filesort` есть - то это плохо. А если все таки нет ... тогда я не понимаю почему он может тормозить.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov здравствуйте. Сделайте ещё одну таблицу, с колонками post_id, user_id, created. И храните там по 20-100 последних записей для каждого пользователя. Для добавления записей в таблицу - используйте триггер, или расширьте хранимую процедуру вставки записи поста. Для удаления старых записей - используйте назначенное задание, которое будет раз в час, удалять старые записи. Дополнительная таблица-кеш поможет быстрее выбирать нужные post_id.